# Why assigning an Image object containing gif to a new instance of Bitmap, breaks the gif

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, bitmap, gif

An Image object contains a gif file and if saved to disk and opened, the gif is displaying properly. However, if a Bitmap object is created from the image instance, and saved, the gif no longer works:

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient();
 client.DownloadFile(new Uri("http://www.ajaxload.info/images/exemples/25.gif"), "25.gif");

 Image original = Image.FromFile("25.gif");
 original.Save("25-WorksFine.gif", ImageFormat.Gif);

 Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(original);
 bmp.Save("25-Broken.gif", ImageFormat.Gif);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image.FromFile uses native GDI+ to load a file using an appropriate decoder

new Bitmap(Image) creates a drawing surface(Graphics) of the size of the image then draws the image on it using Graphics.DrawImage

I suppose in this last case no animation is preserved

Answer (score 4):

`Bitmap` does not support animated files.

Comment: Do you have some resource confirming that? I believe GIFs are mentioned here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Not all GIFs are animated. The documentation is just referring to still images.